# In Apache .htaccess, set Header set Content-disposition, how to pass the filename from QUERY_STRING value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

In Apache `.htaccess`, I have below block to force download.

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /fileName=/">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=download.doc"
</If>
```

This works fine. Now I need to make the filename be the value of query string key "fileName".

I know how to do this in Nginx. Below is the code.

```
if ($arg_fileName) {
    set $fname $arg_fileName;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$fname"';
}
```

How to do this in Apache `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this with the help of mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Save value of fileName URL param in environment variable FILENAME
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)fileName=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=FILENAME:%1]

# Conditionally set header only if FILENAME is set and use this in the header itself
Header set "Content-Disposition" "attachment; filename=\"%{FILENAME}e\"" env=FILENAME
```

`([^&]+)` - Note, however, that you might want to restrict the regex used to match the `fileName` parameter *value*, since not everything is necessarily permitted in the *filename* argument of the HTTP response header. This can [vary by browser and modern browsers do support more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6745788/369434). Note also that the value grabbed from the `QUERY_STRING` is already URL-encoded. So, maybe something like `([\w.-]+)` would be sufficient instead to match just `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`, `.` and `-`?

The `env=FILENAME` argument results in the header only being set when the FILENAME env var exists, so this negates the need for the `<If>` expression.

> ```
> ForceType application/octet-stream
> ```

This isn't strictly necessary to trigger a *download*, it is the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header that does this in any remotely modern browser. In fact, it is not necessarily recommended to send the `application/octet-stream` mime-type for all responses. You should be sending the correct `Content-Type` header for the resource being sent.